# Is $\phi(\infty) - \phi(-\infty) \in 2\pi\mathbb Z$ true if $\int_{\mathbb R} e^{i\phi(x)} e^{ikx} dx=0$ for $k>0$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $\phi: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a sufficiently smooth function such that the limits
$$\phi(\pm\infty) = \lim_{x\to\pm\infty} \phi(x)$$
exist, and suppose that
$$\int_{\mathbb R} e^{i\phi(x)} e^{ikx}  dx=0, \qquad \forall k>0,$$
in the distribution sense.

In this case, can we say that
$$\phi(\infty) - \phi(-\infty) \in 2\pi\mathbb Z\;?$$
A physics paper claims this fact with no proof, but I cannot see why this is true.

Comment: Under your hypothesis, it seems that $\phi$ is in fact constant because its Fourier transform, in the sense of distribution theory, is zero and the Fourier transform is injective on tempered distributions.

Comment: @coudy Thanks a lot for your comment. I made a mistake while formulating the problem mathematically. Now I edited the question to make the hypothesis valid only for $k>0$.

Comment: @coudy In fact $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x e^{ikx} e^{-\epsilon x^2}dx=0$ for all $k\in \Bbb{R}$ (at $k=0$ it is clear and elsewhere the Fourier transform of $x$ is $C\delta'$) so even like this it may not be obvious.

Comment: @reuns That is another good point that I did not think of. Actually I put the regulator $e^{-\epsilon x^2}$ as an artifact, so it seems better to edit the question again.

Comment: a sort of rough outline (with lots of handwaving): let $\hat f$ the Fourier transform of $f=e^{i\phi}$, so $\hat f(k)=0, k<0$ by the hypothesis above; by Fourier inversion $f$ extends to a bounded analytic function in the upper half plane; moving to the unit circle by bending the half plane into the unit disc so $\infty$ goes to $1$ gives that the corresponding $f$ is in $H^{\infty}$ and of bounded variation on the circle as it has limits from both directions at $1$, and then it must be continuous by the Riesz brothers theorem so the limits coincide which is the required result

Comment: the main point is that (bounded) functions on the circle that have Fourier series with only non negative powers of $z=e^{i\theta}$ cannot have jump discontinuities

Comment: @Conrad Thanks very much for your comment! However, I cannot see how one applies the Riesz brothers theorem. Using the conformal equivalence between $\mathbb H$ and $\mathbb D$, define $\tilde f: \mathbb D \to \mathbb C$ as $\tilde f(w) = f\left( i\frac{1+w}{1-w}\right)$. To apply the Riesz brothers theorem, one should consider $\int_0^{2\pi} \tilde f(e^{i\theta}) e^{in\theta} d\theta$. However, the conformal mapping $\mathbb H \to \mathbb D$ does not preserve the "Fourier transform property"!

Comment: @Conrad I also want to know in detail how $f$ can be extended to an analytic function on $\mathbb H$. Using the Fourier inversion,
$$f(x) = \int_0^\infty \hat f(k) e^{ikx} dk,$$
and this behaves "better" as $\mathrm{Im}(x) >0$. However, since $f$ does not decay properly, $\hat f$ is a distribution. How can one show that the integral above is well-defined and gives an analytic function on $\mathbb H$?

Comment: That's why I said this is handwaving but as it comes from physics it may be acceptable; my comment was not intended to be a proof, just a suggestion of why the result may hold at least under suitable hypothesis

Comment: As for the riesz brother theorem I meant not to use it directly but to use it's consequence, namely that bounded functions on the unit circle that come from analytic functions via radial limits cannot have jump discontinuities

Comment: This also follows from the general fact that the conjugate fourier series diverges to infinity at each jump discontinuity of a Fourier series but if that comes from a bounded analytic function, the conjugate Fourier series is more or less the usual conjugate in the Taylor series sense so it is bounded etc